# call servlet from button in a table

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a table which one column is button, how can I send ${user.key} the to the servlet when I click over the button?

```
<form action="InstitutionManagementServlet" method="post" >   
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.AllUsers}" var="user" varStatus="loop">
      <tr>
          <td class="numberWidth">${loop.index + 1}</td>

          <td class="nameWidth" id="${user.key}">${user.value}</td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="Deactivate" value="Deactivate"/></td>
      </tr>
</c:forEach>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two approaches for this.

1. Pass it as button value (and use `<button>` instead of `<input>` so that you can give it a label)

   ```xml
   <form action="InstitutionManagementServlet" method="post">   
       <c:forEach items="${requestScope.AllUsers}" var="user" varStatus="loop">
           <tr>
               <td class="numberWidth">${loop.index + 1}</td>
               <td class="nameWidth" id="${user.key}">${user.value}</td>
               <td><button type="submit" name="Deactivate" value="${user.key}">Deactivate</button></td>
           </tr>
       </c:forEach>
   </form>
   ```

   with

   ```
   String key = request.getParameter("Deactivate");
   // ...
   ```

   ---
2. Or, put each button in its own form with the key as a hidden field.

   ```xml
   <c:forEach items="${requestScope.AllUsers}" var="user" varStatus="loop">
       <tr>
           <td class="numberWidth">${loop.index + 1}</td>
           <td class="nameWidth" id="${user.key}">${user.value}</td>
           <td>
               <form action="InstitutionManagementServlet" method="post">
                   <input type="submit" name="Deactivate" value="Deactivate" />
                   <input type="hidden" name="key" value="${user.key}" />
               </form>
           </td>
       </tr>
   </c:forEach>
   ```

   with

   ```
   String key = request.getParameter("key");
   // ...
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Make it part of a hidden field

```
<form action="InstitutionManagementServlet" method="post" >   
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.AllUsers}" var="user" varStatus="loop">
      <tr>
          <td class="numberWidth">${loop.index + 1}</td>

          <td class="nameWidth" id="${user.key}">${user.value}</td>
          <td
              <input type="submit" name="Deactivate" value="Deactivate"/>
              <input type="hidden" name"key" value="${user.key}"/>
          </td>
      </tr>
</c:forEach>
</form>
```

And read it using `String[] keys = request.getParameterValues("key");` in your servlet. You will get all keys.

Comment: How would you know about the particular user you'd like to deactivate?